# Do I need to remove this residue from my floor and if so, how?

Tags: flooring, subfloor, adhesive, hardwood, vinyl

We’re in the process of laying down vinyl planks and want to tackle the kitchen next. We recently removed glued down hardwood and are left with this. We’ve tried sanding the residue down and it hasn’t been very effective. It’s a fairly flat surface with the glue.

- What should we do to remove it?
- Should we just go ahead with laying down the vinyl with some padding? (Filling in any gaps first of course).

We’re trying to DIY a lot of our new home because saving money is a bit of a priority right now.

[image]

Comment: Planks can deal with limited height differences, usually about 2/16 inch, but the flatter the better.  Most of that floor seems okay, but the bottom end is where you might want to do some more work.  Most planks want some thin padding.  Read instructions for it's needs.

Comment: I would scrape that smooth-*ish*.  Doesn't need to be totally flat, but ferinstance those big chunks in the foreground—those gotta go, or at least be knocked down near flat.

Answer (score 0):

If the floor is flat enough to be within the specs declared by the flooring manufacturer, then you really don't need to do anything except hit the high spots with a sander or scraper.

There are a multitude of products designed for removing adhesives and other sticky residues. Things like Goo Gone™ or Goof Off™ (no affiliation or recommendation).

These products are mostly acetone so if one of them works OK you might try to buy some acetone in bulk as a *much* less expensive option than dozens of little containers.

Comment: Caveat: Acetone is *highly* flammable. Do not use in any nontrivial quantity without good active ventilation. A respirator with organic-solvents cartridges is also highly recommended. Personally, in this case, I'd suggest sticking with mechanical scraping.